# Ubuntu load and hang on live USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, uefi, secure-boot

I seem to have run into some difficulties trying to install Linux alongside my USB. I made a bootable USB stick and done all the UEFI firmware settings from which I disabled fast boot.

Now when I run my USB from the boot menu, the first screen shown is the options for Linux: "try it for free", "install Ubuntu" and so on.

Regardless of the option I choose, the screen just goes blank and that's it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of Linux? Sometimes you've got to set `nomodeset` option to get the graphics driver to work, depending on the hardware.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 fixed the problem for me.